# Bash Shell: Infinite Loop

Tags: bash, shell, infinite-loop

The problem is the following I have a file that each line has this form:

```
id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser
```

i want to sort alphabetically all the firstnames in that file and print them one on each line but each name only once

i have created the following program but for some reason it creates an infinite loop:

```
array1=()
while read LINE
do
    if [ ${LINE:0:1} != '#' ]
    then 
        IFS="|"
        array=($LINE)
        if [[ "${array1[@]}" != "${array[2]}" ]]
        then
                array1+=("${array[2]}")
        fi
    fi
done < $3
echo ${array1[@]} | awk 'BEGIN{RS=" ";} {print $1}' | sort
```

NOTES

- `if [ ${LINE:0:1} != '#' ]` : this command is used because there are comments in the file that i dont want to print
- `$3` : filename
- `array1` : is used for all the seperate names

Comment: I don't see any way that could be an infinite loop. `while read` will stop when it gets to the end of the file.

Comment: That `awk` command can be replaced with `tr ' ' '\n'`

Comment: i don' see either but that's what it actually happens. Try to run it if you want.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, then it will show every line as it's being executed. This is how you debug shell scripts.

Comment: I'll try it thank you.

Comment: `"${array1[@]}" != "${array[2]}"` doesn't seem right. You're comparing the name in the current row with all the names that have been saved before. That won't test if the new name is already in the array.

Comment: If you only want to see a name once, just use `sort -u`.

Comment: You could also use `awk` to read the CSV file, instead of doing that with a shell loop.

Comment: The whole thing can be done with: `awk -F'|' '!/^#/ {print $2}' | sort -u`

Comment: I just tried the script, it didn't infinite loop.

Comment: It does it to me however.

Comment: It worked with the way you proposed thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Of course i do.

Comment: To be accurate it is awk -F'|' '!/^#/ {print $2}' $3 | sort -u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, there's a MUCH simpler and cleaner way to achieve this, without having to mess with the IFS variable or using arrays. You can use "for" to do this:

First I created a file with the same structure as yours:

```
$ cat file
id|lastName|Douglas|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser
id|lastName|Tim|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser
id|lastName|Andrew|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser
id|lastName|Sasha|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser
#id|lastName|Carly|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser
id|lastName|Madson|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser
```

Here's the script I wrote using "for":

```
#!/bin/bash

for LINE in `cat file | grep -v "^#" | awk -F'|' '{print$3}' | sort -u`
do
        echo $LINE
done
```

And here's the output of this script:

```
$ ./script.sh
Andrew
Douglas
Madson
Sasha
Tim
```

Explanation:

```
for LINE in `cat file`
```

Creates a loop that reads each line of "file". The commands between ` are run by linux, for example, if you wanted to store the date inside of a variable you could use "VARDATE=`date`".

```
grep -v "^#"
```

The option -v is used to exclude results matching the pattern, in this case the pattern is "^#". The "^" character means "line begins with". So grep -v "^#" means "exclude lines beginning with #".

```
awk -F'|' '{print$3}'
```

The -F option switches the column delimiter from the default (the default is a space) to whatever you put between ' after it, in this case the "|" character.
The '{print$3}' prints the 3rd column.

```
sort -u
```

And the "sort -u" command to sort the names alphabetically.